# Can I do the proof of $\lim x^2 + 3x + 2_{x \to 3} = 20$ in the following way? :

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, epsilon-delta

From the definition of epsilon delta we know,

$0 < |x-3| < \delta$

And,

$|x^2 + 3x + 2 - 20| < \epsilon$

Or, $|(x + 6)*(x-3)| < \epsilon$ [After factoring out]

Now I am going to go stray from traditional way,

As we don't have any control over $x+6$ let's bound it, we know :

$-\delta < x - 3 < \delta$
or, $9 - \delta < x + 6 < 9 + \delta$

If this is true then this also must be true: $|(x-3)|*|(x+6)| < |(x-3)|*(9+\delta)$

Now we can write it as like this :
$|(x-3)|*(9+\delta) < \epsilon$

or, $|(x-3)| < \epsilon/(9+\delta)$

So, $\delta = \epsilon/(9+\delta)$
Using the quadric equation,

$\delta = (-9 + √(81 + 4\epsilon) )/2$

So instead of assuming delta as $1$ or $2$ I just assumed it to be any number and it worked out nicely and tried some values with it and it worked too. So is this correct way of doing it? I know I didn't complete the proof but just wanted to know whether this way is correct or not.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Delta, epsilon should be written `\delta, \epsilon`, and all formulas enclosed by dollar signs.

Answer (score 2):

Your method seems a bit overcomplicated. Do $$|(x+6)(x-3)|=|(x-3+9)(x-3)|\leq|x-3|^2+9|x-3|$$

We would need $\delta=\min\{1,\varepsilon/10\}$.

Then if $|x-3|<\delta$, we have $|x-3|^2\leq|x-3|$ which means $$|x-3|^2+9|x-3|\leq |x-3|+9|x-3|=10|x-3|$$
and the result follows.